# IOS adding UIProgressView to AVFoundation AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` to record videos and I want to add a `UIProgressView` to represent how much time there is left before the video stops recording.

I set a max duration of 15 seconds:

```
CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(15, 50);
[[self movieFileOutput] setMaxRecordedDuration:maxDuration];
```

I can't seem to find if `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` has a callback for when the video is recording or for when recording begins. My question is, how can I get updates on the progress of the recording? Or if this isn't something that is available, how can I tell when recording begins in order to start a timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I was able to add a `UIProgressView`

`recording` is a property of `AVCaptureFileOutput` which is extended by `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`

I have a variable movieFileOutput of type `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` that I am using to capture data to a QuickTime movie.

```
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *movieFileOutput;
```

I added an observer to the recording property to detect a change in recording.

```
[self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"movieFileOutput.recording"
              options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)
              context:RecordingContext];
```

Then in the callback method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;
```

I created a while loop to be executed in the background, then I made sure to dispatch updates to the view on the main thread like this:

```
    dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{ // Background task started
        // While the movie is recording, update the progress bar
        while ([[self movieFileOutput] isRecording]) {
            double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds([[self movieFileOutput] recordedDuration]);
            double time = CMTimeGetSeconds([[self movieFileOutput] maxRecordedDuration]);
            CGFloat progress = (CGFloat) (duration / time);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // Here I dispatch to main queue and update the progress view.
                [self.progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you updating the UI in an infinite loop?    That must be terribly inefficient.