# Record multiple videos and update progress bar using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcam

I am creating an **Instagram** kind of video recording and posting app. I have a max recording duration of 15 sec and i need to show a progress bar.[This link helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501299/ios-adding-uiprogressview-to-avfoundation-avcapturemoviefileoutput) .Code here.

```
 CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(15, 50);

 [[self movieFileOutput] setMaxRecordedDuration:maxDuration];
```

As a result `stopRecording` is not called also `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` is called at the end of 15 secs. I need to create 3 videos of 5secs each and update progress bar accordingly so that at the end of 15 secs my progress bar is full just like **Instagram**. please help

Comment: Long ago. I think u solved that but let me tell u I am doing almost the same task, just wants to know if u solved that or not.